# Java builder classes generics hierarchy: how to make build() return correct method

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I have this class structure:

```
                Stuff
              /       \
   Food
     |   
   FastFood                  Drink
     |                        |
   Pizza                    Juice
  /     \                   /    \
 |     SicilianPizza       |    OrangeJuice
 |                      AppleJuice
CaliforniaPizza
```

I can create pizza and juice objects using builders like this:

```
CaliforniaPizza californiaPizze = CaliforniaPizza.builder(2)
                .addTopping("Tomatoes").addOlives(true).build();
        SicilianPizza sicilianPizza = SicilianPizza.builder(1)
                .addTopping("Bacon").addCheese(false).build();

        AppleJuice appleJuice = AppleJuice.builder(40)
                .setPrice(120).setAlcoholVolume(0).setAppleColor("yellow").build();
        OrangeJuice orangeJuice = OrangeJuice.builder(35).setOrangeSize(8).build();
```

Every setter method of the builder returns correct object:

[image]

I'd like to create a method that would accept a `FastFood.Builder` object and use it to create a `FastFood` object that would pass it to another method:

```
public void makeFat(FastFood fastFood)  {...}
```

But I can't: setter methods don't return `FastFood`, but rather its parents:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my generics? How could that be accomplished?

```
package pizza;

import java.util.*;

class TestStuff {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliforniaPizza californiaPizze = CaliforniaPizza.builder(2)
                .addTopping("Tomatoes").addOlives(true).build();
        SicilianPizza sicilianPizza = SicilianPizza.builder(1)
                .addTopping("Bacon").addCheese(false).build();

        AppleJuice appleJuice = AppleJuice.builder(40)
                .setPrice(120).setAlcoholVolume(0).setAppleColor("yellow").build();
        OrangeJuice orangeJuice = OrangeJuice.builder(35).setOrangeSize(8).build();
    }

    public FastFood testFood(FastFood.Builder fastFoodBuilder)  {
       //return  fastFoodBuilder.setMealType("fd").addOlives(true).setPrice(20).build();
    }

    public void makeFat(FastFood fastFood)  {}
}



abstract class Stuff {
    protected double price;

    protected Stuff()  {}

    protected abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>>  {
        protected abstract Stuff build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setPrice(double price)  {
            Stuff.this.price = price;
            return self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Food extends Stuff {
    protected String mealType; //breakfast/dinner/etc

    protected Food()  {}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Stuff.Builder<T> {
        protected abstract Food build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setMealType(String mealType)  {
            Food.this.mealType = mealType;
            return self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class FastFood extends Food  {
    protected int harm;

    protected FastFood() {}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Food.Builder<T> {
        protected abstract FastFood build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setHarm(int harm)  {
            FastFood.this.harm = harm;
            return self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Pizza extends FastFood {
    protected List<String> toppings = new ArrayList<>();  //optional
    protected int size;  //obligatory

    protected Pizza(int size)  {this.size = size;}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends FastFood.Builder<T>  {
        public T addTopping(String topping)  {
            toppings.add(topping);
            return self();
        }
    }
}

class CaliforniaPizza extends Pizza {
    private boolean addOlives;

    private CaliforniaPizza(int size) {super(size);}

    public static Builder builder(int size)  {return new CaliforniaPizza(size).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public CaliforniaPizza build()  {
            return CaliforniaPizza.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder addOlives(boolean addOlives)  {
            CaliforniaPizza.this.addOlives = addOlives;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

class SicilianPizza extends Pizza {
    private boolean addCheese;

    private SicilianPizza(int size)  {super(size);}

    public static Builder builder(int size)  {
        return new SicilianPizza(size).new Builder();
    }

    public class Builder extends Pizza.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public SicilianPizza build()  {return SicilianPizza.this;}

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder addCheese(boolean addCheese)  {
            SicilianPizza.this.addCheese = addCheese;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

abstract class Drink extends Stuff {
    protected double density;
    protected double alcoholVolume;

    protected Drink(double density)  {this.density = density;}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Stuff.Builder<T>  {
        protected abstract Drink build();
        protected abstract T self();

        public T setAlcoholVolume(double alcoholVolume)  {
            Drink.this.alcoholVolume = alcoholVolume;
            return self();
        }
    }
}

abstract class Juice extends Drink {
    private String color;

    protected Juice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Drink.Builder<T>  {
        public Builder<T> setColor(String color)  {
            Juice.this.color = color;
            return self();
        }
    }
}
class AppleJuice extends Juice {
    private String appleColor;

    private AppleJuice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public static Builder builder(double density)  {return new AppleJuice(density).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public AppleJuice build()  {
            return AppleJuice.this;
        }

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setAppleColor(String appleColor)  {
            AppleJuice.this.appleColor = appleColor;
            return this;
        }
    }
}

class OrangeJuice extends Juice{
    private int orangeSize;

    private OrangeJuice(double density)  {super(density);}

    public static Builder builder(double density)  {return new OrangeJuice(density).new Builder();}

    public class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>  {
        @Override
        public OrangeJuice build()  {return OrangeJuice.this;}

        @Override
        public Builder self()  {return this;}

        public Builder setOrangeSize(int orangeSize)  {
            OrangeJuice.this.orangeSize = orangeSize;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That the first 10 entries retrieved from the table have a NULL or empty string for "amenities" does not indicate an error.  You can't order a sandwich at a fire hydrant, this is not a bug.  Try `SELECT amenity FROM planet_osm_point where amenity is not null and amenity <> ''`LIMIT 10

Comment: It seems to be a problem of your IDE. Eclipse infers `FastFood2` for `build()`. Yet maybe your IDE recovers if you turn the method signature to `FastFood testBuilder(FastFood2.Builder<? extends FastFood2.Builder<?>> builder)`.

Comment: @CoronA Sorry, I realized that my last code was harder to use and edited it. It can be copypasted all at once now. I'm going to try your advice now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the line:

```
public FastFood testFood(FastFood.Builder fastFoodBuilder) {
```

But also:

```
abstract class FastFood extends Food  {
    ...
    public abstract class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Food.Builder<T> {
```

There should be a warning saying that `FastFood.Builder` is a generic type.

The parameter type needs to be made appropriately generic. A wildcard will do (constraints will be inferred).

```
public FastFood testFood(FastFood.Builder<?> fastFoodBuilder) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with the code.

Class `FastFood.Builder` is generic: `class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends Food.Builder<T>`.

In the method `FastFood testFood(FastFood.Builder fastFoodBuilder)` the builder is declared **without specifying the type** `T`.

For example, `AppleJuice` specifies the parameter `T` type: `class Builder extends Juice.Builder<Builder>`.

The same problem will be present for `Drink.Builder`:

```
public static Drink testDrink(Drink.Builder drinkBuilder) {
    return drinkBuilder
            .setPrice(100) // returns Stuff.Builder
            .setAlcoholVolume(0.7) //Error: cannot resolve method
            .build();
}
```

To fix this, make method `testFood` generic accepting parameter `FastFood.Builder<T>`:

```
public static <T extends FastFood.Builder<T>> FastFood testFood(FastFood.Builder<T> fastFoodBuilder) {
    return fastFoodBuilder.setMealType("fd").setHarm(1).setPrice(20).build();
}
```

The same is true for methods accepting `Drink.Builder`:

```
public static <T extends Drink.Builder<T>> Drink testDrink(Drink.Builder<T> drinkBuilder) {
    return drinkBuilder.setPrice(100).setAlcoholVolume(0.7).build();
}
```

Usage example:

```
FastFood californiaPizza1 = testFood(CaliforniaPizza.builder(2));
```

In order to call `addOlives(boolean)` method and avoid casting from `FastFood` to a concrete class (e.g. `CaliforniaPizza`), it's more convenient to return builder from a method:

```
public static <T extends FastFood.Builder<T>> T testFoodBuilder(FastFood.Builder<T> fastFoodBuilder) {
    return fastFoodBuilder.setMealType("fd").setHarm(1).setPrice(20);
}
```

And the usage:

```
CaliforniaPizza californiaPizza2 = 
            testFoodBuilder(CaliforniaPizza.builder(2))
                    .addOlives(true)
                    .build();
```